# SQL DELETE & .import effects/references two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Do you know what may cause the referencing/dependency between two tables in SQLite? Building in sqlite3, Terminal, OS X 10.12.5

OVERVIEW:

I have built a small set of database tables (full schema at the bottom). 
However, two of the tables appear to be referencing each other. Where on .import to either table, both tables, are affected. Likewise, on DELETE FROM either table, on any column, both tables, are affected.

DETAILS:

Action specifics/step-through:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Wine; -> NO DATA
sqlite> SELECT * FROM WineVarietal; -> NO DATA
sqlite> .import fileLocation/fileName.csv Wine
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Wine; -> NEW ROWS SHOW
```

[image: SELECT * FROM Wine after initial .import to Wine]

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM WineVarietal; -> NEW ROWS FROM Wine TABLE SHOW
```

[image: SELECT * FROM WineVarietal after initial .import to Wine]

```
sqlite> .import fileLocation/fileName.csv WineVarietal
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Wine; -> NEW ROWS FROM WineVarietal TABLE SHOW
```

[image: SELECT * FROM Wine after initial .import to WineVarietal]

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM WineVarietal; -> NEW ROWS SHOW
```

[image: SELECT * FROM WineVarietal after initial .import to WineVarietal]

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM WineVarietal WHERE VarietalID > 3;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Wine; -> ROWS ARE MISSING FROM Wine TABLE
```

[image: SELECT * FROM Wine after DELETE FROM WineVarietal]

As is hopefully apparent from the following step-through, modification of the individual tables, directly affects the other table. Modification of the child affects the parent and modification of the parent completely affects the child. I imagine there must be table setting creating this dependency.

Full Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Appellation(AppellationID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, AppellationName TEXT, AppellationState TEXT, AppelationCountry TEXT);
CREATE TABLE Style(StyleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, StyleName TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Vinter(VinterID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, VinterName TEXT, VinterCountry TEXT, VinterState TEXT, VinterRegion TEXT, VinterCity TEXT);
CREATE TABLE Varietal(VarietalID INT PRIMARY KEY, VarietalName TEXT);
CREATE TABLE User(UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, UserName TEXT, UserPhoto BLOB, UserSignupDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE Importer(ImporterID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Importer TEXT, ImporterCity TEXT, ImporterState TEXT, ImporterZip INTEGER, ImporterURL TEXT);
CREATE TABLE Retailer(RetailerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, RetailerName TEXT, RetailerStreet TEXT, RetailerCity TEXT, RetailerState TEXT, RetailerCountry TEXT);
CREATE TABLE Estate(EstateID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Estate TEXT, VinterID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (VinterID) REFERENCES Vinter(VinterID));
CREATE TABLE Wine(
WineID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
VinterID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
StyleID INTEGER NOT NULL,
AppellationID INTEGER,
Vintage INTEGER NOT NULL,
WineName TEXT,
EstateID INTEGER,
BarcodeImage BLOB,
LabelImage BLOB,
ImporterID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (VinterID) REFERENCES Vinter(VinterID),
FOREIGN KEY (StyleID) REFERENCES Style(StyleID),
FOREIGN KEY (AppellationID) REFERENCES Appellation(AppellationID),
FOREIGN KEY (EstateID) REFERENCES Estate(EstateID),
FOREIGN KEY (ImporterID) REFERENCES Importer(ImporterID));
CREATE TABLE "WineVarietal"(WineID INTEGER NOT NULL, VarietalID INTEGER NOT NULL, Percent INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (WineID) REFERENCES Wine(WineID), FOREIGN KEY (VarietalID) REFERENCES Varietal(VarietalID));
CREATE TABLE Tasting(
TastingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
TastingTimeStamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
UserID INTEGER NOT NULL,
WineID INTEGER NOT NULL,
RetailerID INTEGER,
Price INTEGER,
Rating INTEGER,
Review TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID),
FOREIGN KEY (WineID) REFERENCES Wine(WineID),
FOREIGN KEY (RetailerID) REFERENCES Retailer(RetailerID));
/* No STAT tables available */
```

Comment: You mean when you import to one table, new records are added to the other?

Comment: Correct. Action on one table directly affect the other.

Comment: Please specifiy exactly what the unwanted effect is.

Comment: @CL. Sure thing. I've updated my question to include a step through to help clarify.

Comment: Is this really the schema of the database file you're using? There aren't any triggers, are they?

Comment: @CL. Correct, this is the complete schema.

Comment: What you've described should be impossible. Please provide a [mcve] of the actual import data.

Comment: @CL. Understood. Let me see what I can do to provide that example. (first I've seen that link - I appreciate it.)

Comment: I have been unable to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are directly manipulating parent table **Wine** ,child table **WineVarietal** is affected as WineID is referencing key.

Comment: Should modifying a child have an affect on the parent? I've updated my question to include the specifics of my scenario.